# eOS Hera freezes, every day, several times a day

Tags: system, release-hera

Not sure what's happening. eOS Hera 5.1 freezes at least once a day, sometimes more. It happens when all I have open is Firefox or Chrome. The cursor stops moving then all keys are unresponsive. All I can do is to force a shut down. Any ideas?
Thanks
Fred

---

No worries, I have now returned to Ubuntu 19.10 and it all works like a charm. No need to answer anymore

Answer (score 0):

Well OK this is still happening and no one seems to have an answer. I love eOS but can't work with it like this. I guess I will have to switch OS.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:
1.) Are you on a laptop? Does this occur when the system attempts to suspend or go in to standby? If so, then it could be an issue with your machine's DSDT/ACPI tables. There are ways to get around this by using the "acpi_osi" kernel argument. Reply for more information or Google/duckduckgo "Linux acpi_osi".
2.) When it freezes, have you tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to a terminal? If you can get a textual login prompt, then that's a first step in to troubleshooting.  Log in this way and then run "dmesg" to see if there are any errors at the bottom of the output. You can also safely reboot from here via "sudo reboot".

Hopefully this is a start.
-Reed

Comment: Also, always be sure to tell us what type of computer you're using, etc. Otherwise, there's not much to go on. =]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. 
I am on a System 76 laptop (Galago Pro 13") (well, the German version, actually), Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz with 16 GB of RAM and a SSD of 256.
No, the freezes happen very randomly, not when the system tries to suspend. It can be while navigating the web on Chrome, or Firefox or Opera. That is most of what I do so not sure if it would happen when doing something else. 
I can certainly try again the CTRL-ALT-F1 option but I did before and nothing happened, the whole shebang was completely frozen, so I always have to do a hard reboot.
Any better idea? 
Cheers
Fred