# eOS 6.1 Jólnir freezes once every ~2 days

Tags: crash, release-jolnir

I have only recently started using eOS and am loving it.
But every once in a while, the entire os freezes. I am unable to access tty, the cursor does not move, nothing works and I have to do a hard reboot.

I am dual booting Windows 11 and eOS 6.1.
The freezes are happening when I have a lot of Firefox and chromium tabs open.

I also mostly use an external monitor with the Laptop lid down.

Since the GPU was pulling a lot of power I switched to Intel integrated Graphics:

```
glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
```

This gives the output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
```

Some system information:

```
OS: elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir x86_64
Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q
```

Please let me know what further information would be necessary to diagnose and fix the issue. I really do not want to go back to Kubuntu.

This seems to be an old unaddressed issue as well: [eos-hera-freezes-every-day-several-times-a-day](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22497/eos-hera-freezes-every-day-several-times-a-day)

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Having eOS 6.1, randomly freezes couple times per day. I only have eOS6.1 in my MacBook Air, Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i5-3427U CPU @ 1.80GHz.

However, this is quite new feauture (2-3 weeks or so). Never happened with eOS 6.0 but cannot say that this is related to the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, linux noob here.
eOS 6.1 has been running (more or less) flawlessly for about five months now.
Only issue I had in the past was that sometimes it froze. This happened once to a few times a week. If I wait long enough it just continues... sometimes. But I sometimes am an impatient person, so I reboot. After a cold restart and reboot I see the notification for "new updates available". Always after a freeze/reboot. This can't be a coincidence IMHO.

---

But OT, I have been having this same issue since today...
total freeze after what feels like the same amount of time (like 15 min. after boot or so). But I have eOS installed on an encrypted drive and run Virtual Box on eOS for other OSes.

Keyboard/Mouse dead, so no way to access tty or do the reboot-thing (that ain't working anyway).

Is there like a log one can dig into?
Or some program that one can run that logs everything in real time until the point of failure?

thx
love n peace